# Spring Reactor: Mono.zip fails on empty Mono

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I am using Spring Reactor 3.1.0.M3 and have a use case where I need to merge Mono's from multiple sources. I found that if one of the Monos is an empty Mono, zip fails without an error.

Example:

```
Mono<String> m1 = Mono.just("A");
Mono<String> m2 = Mono.just("B");
Mono<String> m3 = Mono.empty();

Mono<String> combined = Mono.zip(strings -> {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (Object string : strings) {
        sb.append((String) string);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}, m1, m2, m3);
System.out.println("Combined " + combined.block());
```

When m3 is added, the combinator is skipped in the response is null. When I remove m3, it all works as expected and "AB" is returned.
Is there a way I could handle this by detecting the empty Mono?
Also, is there a way to have the combinator method know the type of the object instead of having to cast?

Comment: for small number of Mono there's Mono.when (we're actually thinking about changing that to zip in 3.1.0). It won't change the empy-if-one-source-empty behavior though...

Comment: I only have 3 Mono's in this example, but in the actual code I use Iterable. So it would be useful if I could filter out empty Mono's or handle it somehow.   At the moment the combined Mono resolves to null with no indication of what the cause is. When Mono's are produced by multiple sources there will be no guarantee that none would be empty

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The zip operator doesn't behave like this. It would be in fact counter-intuitive: your code is expecting a Tuple of 3 elements and you're only getting two?!?

In this case, you're in control and only you can decide what's a good default value if none is provided (remember, `null` values are forbidden by the reactive streams specification).

```
Mono<String> m1 = Mono.just("A");
Mono<String> m2 = Mono.just("B");
Mono<String> m3 = Mono.empty().defaultIfEmpty("");

Mono<String> combined = Mono.zip(m1, m2, m3).map(t -> {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(t.getT1());
    sb.append(t.getT2());
    sb.append(t.getT3());
    return sb.toString();
});
```

## Edit

You seem to be confused by the nature of a `Publisher` type, see:

> if one of the Monos is an empty Mono, zip fails without an error

and

> So if I was to try and zip Mono's and for some reason one is empty, the zip would fail and I cannot seem to put in any code to safeguard against that

An empty `Mono` isn't a failure case: it's just that no value is emitted and it is completed successfully. You can verify that by changing the code sample:

```
    combined.subscribe(
            s -> System.out.println("element: " + s), // doesn't execute
            s -> System.out.println("error: " + s), // doesn't execute
            () -> { System.out.println("complete!"); // prints
    });
```

So depending on your requirements, you can:

- apply a `defaultIfEmpty` operator on those 3 `Mono` instances, if there are convenient default values you can rely on
- apply a `defaultIfEmpty` operator on the combined `Mono`, with a default value or even transform that into an error message with `combined.switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(...))`

Comment: I am trying to understand how this would work in an environment with multiple producers of Mono<?> not under my control. So if I was to try and zip Mono's and for some reason one is empty, the zip would fail and I cannot seem to put in any code to safeguard against that.
I am using Reactor 3.1.0.M3 which does not seem to have zip with the signature in your sample

Comment: I edited my answer to underline the fact that an empty Mono is not a failure case

Comment: Looks like the answer need an update since 'Mono.when()' return 'Mono<Void>'

Answer (score 9):

In case of `String` it is quite easy to define a default value for the empty case which solves the issue nicely as described in Brian's answer. However, for other custom types it might be difficult to create an empty object for one reason or another. An alternative for these cases is to use `Optional`. This solution has some heavy boilerplate, though.

```java
Mono<Optional<String>> m1 = Mono.just("A").map(Optional::of).defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty());
Mono<Optional<String>> m2 = Mono.just("B").map(Optional::of).defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty());
Mono<Optional<String>> m3 = Mono.<String>empty().map(Optional::of).defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty());

Mono<String> combined = Mono.zip(strings -> {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (Object string : strings) {
        ((Optional<String>) string).ifPresent(sb::append);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}, m1, m2, m3);
System.out.println("Combined " + combined.block());
```

Answer (score 2):

**Mono.zip**

An error or empty completion of any source will cause other sources to be cancelled and the resulting Mono to immediately error or complete, respectively.

When a Mono source completes without value, if you still want to continue the execution of other sources then **Mono.zipDelayError** is the best choice for you.

Answer (score 1):

Should be `Mono.zip`:

```
Mono<String> myStrings = Mono.zip(monoA, monoB)
  .map(tuple -> {
    return new StringBuffer()
      .append(t.getT1());
      .append(t.getT2());
});
```

Also instead of forbidden `null` or `Mono.empty()` passed `zip()`, you can pass `Mono.just(Optional.empty())`.

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure, my example is basically, Brian Clozel's but with small edit to highlight for other dataTypes.

```
Mono<String> m1 = Mono.just("A");
Mono<String> m2 = Mono.just("B");
Mono<String> m3 = Mono.fromSupplier(() -> new String());

Mono<String> combined = Mono.zip(m1, m2, m3).map(t -> {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(t.getT1());
    sb.append(t.getT2());
    sb.append(t.getT3());
    return sb.toString();
});
```

ie so, zip, will ignore an entry when it's null ie Mono.empty. So for it to compleate, you need to have a non null value, a empty string in this case, but a new instance of the data type for you to check later in the code is also good