# Merging Mono<?> that can be empty

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

I think this piece of code should explain most of what I want to achieve

```
fun main() {
    val mono1 = Mono.just(1)
    val mono2 = Mono.just("two")
    val mono3 = Mono.empty<Boolean>()

    data class Aggregated(
        val f1: Int? = null,
        val f2: String? = null,
        val f3: Boolean? = null,
    )

    Mono.zip(mono1, mono2, mono3)
        .map { tuple -> Aggregated(tuple.t1, tuple.t2, tuple.t3) }
        .subscribe(
            { c -> logger.info { c.toString() } },
            { e -> logger.error(e) { e.message } },
            {      logger.info { ">> Done! " } }
        )
}
```

Basically I want to aggregate multiple async calls into an aggregated result and this will "fall off" because `mono3` emits a `Mono.empty()` that essentially drops the signal from the `Mono.zip`.

What I am expecting is

```
Aggregated(
  f1: 1,
  f2: "two",
  f3: null
)
```

This seems like a simplistic thing to do but I cannot find a solution.

A few points:

1. I am merging multiple Monos
2. The Monos could return any type of data classes
3. The Monos could emit a `Mono.empty()`

Comment: Your only solution in this case is to have a fallback value that will be your "empty" value (defaultIfEmpty). for instance a string you could use "" or "EMPTY". False for a boolean and -1 for int.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Reactor: Mono.zip fails on empty Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45727372/spring-reactor-mono-zip-fails-on-empty-mono)

Comment: it kinda answer my question to some point. it maybe straightforward to consider a "default fallback" for the empty signal, and especially so for "normal" data like Int, String, Boolean. but there's no such thing for data class. best i can do is perhaps do a `Map<String, Any?>` conversion temporarily.